# how to syncronize functions in swift

Tags: ios, swift, firebase

```
@IBAction func seePostingButtonClicked(_ sender: Any) {
    postRef.queryOrdered(byChild: "uid").queryEqual(toValue: otherUID).observe(.childAdded, with:{
        snapshot in
        print("snapshot.value is \(snapshot.value!)")
        if let postDict = snapshot.value as? Dictionary<String, AnyObject> {
            let key = snapshot.key
            let post = Post(postKey: key, postData: postDict)
            print("post is \(post)")
            let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
            dateFormatter.dateFormat = "EEE, MMM d, yyyy, h:mma"
            let stringOfDate = post.dateForFilters!
            let date = dateFormatter.date(from: stringOfDate)!
            if date.timeIntervalSinceNow > 0{
                otherUserPosts.append(post)
            }
        }
    })
    print(otherUserPosts)
    DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 2.5, execute: {
        self.present(otherUserActivePostsVC, animated: true, completion: nil)
    })
}
```

Currently, the only way I know how to make this next view controller present populated with data is to add a 2.5 second delay. That approach works short term, but should my app grow such that large numbers are using it, I will have to adapt to a more precise way of launching the view controller after the prior query function has completed. How do you do that? Here is how I set the presented view controller:

```
let otherUserActivePostsVC = UIStoryboard(name:"HomeScreen", bundle:MUPbundle3).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "otherUserPostsVC") as UIViewController
```

That declaration above is made outside of any class or view controller so it serves as a variable that is meaningful throughout my project.

Below is another example of not knowing how to trigger the launching of a new view controller without the timer so that the retrieveOtherUserData() function is completed first.

```
@IBAction func messageButtonClicked(_ sender: AnyObject) {
    comingFromChatListingCell = false
    let messageButton = sender as! UIButton
    let selectedPost = filteredPosts[(messageButton.tag)]
    otherUID = selectedPost.uId
    retrieveOtherUserData()
    JSQAlternateVC.senderDisplayName = userFirstName
    JSQAlternateVC.senderId = userID
    DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 1, execute: {
         homeVC.present(JSQAlternateVC, animated: true, completion: nil)
    })
}
```

Comment: Put the presenting of the next view controller _inside_ the `queryOrdered` completion handler closure. By the way, if that closure doesn't run on the main queue, make sure to dispatch the `self.present()` to the main queue yourself, e.g. `DispatchQueue.main.async { self.present(...) }`. But if that closure already runs on the main queue, then that's not necessary.

Comment: Thanks. When I try it your way it gives me the error "Application tried to present modally an active controller" even though the controller shouldn't have been active as it's the first time it's being presented. When I do it the way I showed above, it yields no errors.

Comment: You edit looks better. Based upon your error message, it sounds like `JSQAlternateVC` is already active and there cannot be presented. Show us how you set that variable. Have you already presented it or otherwise added it to the view controller hierarchy?